# Mouse configuration file

Tags: 12.04, mouse, settings, system-settings

Which file (name & path) store the settings made in this window?

[image: Settings -> Mouse and Touchpad]

Answer (score 8):

The settings for the mouse shown in your screenshot can be accessed from the `dconf-editor`.  If it is not installed you can install it by running: `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`.

Open `dconf` and navigate to: `org -> gnome -> settings-daemon -> peripheral -> mouse`.  Here are some screenshots that show how each option relates to the settings.

[image]

[image]

You can also find the settings in `gconf` under `gnome -> peripherals -> mouse`.  Here is a screenshot for `gconf` as well.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

dconf and gconf does not help me what I need.

I wanted to trace configuration file to make changes directly in it.

Comment: @DragosSurdescu Are you still looking for an answer?  I know how to change these from the command line, though I'm not sure it's possible to change the file direct.